# Как определить длину числа

Tags: c#, .net

Застрял на задании в определении длины числа типа int. Проблема в том, что код считает длины всех чисел в тесте (+ и -), кроме int.MinValue, в отладчике возвращает NaN. Не могу понять почему так происходит, помогите пожалуйста.

```
public static byte GetLengthWithCascadedIfElse(int number)
    {
        if (number < 0)
        {
            return (byte)Math.Floor(Math.Log10((int)(-number)) + 1);
        }
        else if (number == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return (byte)Math.Floor(Math.Log10((int)number) + 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Обязательно нужно формулой или можно другой алгоритм, типа "делить на 10 и считать число разрядов"?

Comment: Не обязательно формулой, наткнулся на похожий вопрос с таким подходом.

Comment: А можно пример данных, на которых работает неправильно? (кроме `int.MinValue`, разумеется) У меня в отладчике никакого NaN не наблюдается.

Comment: @VladD Смешно. Проверил код автора, немодифицированный  - у меня работает без проблем на всех юнит-тестах.

Comment: @AK: Специально проверил крайние случаи типа 10, 1000, 1_000_000_000, везде вроде бы работает как надо.

Comment: вообще, тут не принято переписывать код автора вопроса, но лишние `else` можно убрать, т.к. `return` выходит из метода. так код станет компактнее и читабельнее, как по мне.

Comment: @return: Ну тогда уже и лишний cast к `int` стоит убрать. И переписать на switch expression.

Comment: Как-то так: https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFDIEYE8AuBTABAcW0wBlsA7Ac0wAsB1ASxoGEBDAZwGMXhtgBJAGYBRADZtsACnplMuMgFcAtqmwAnAJS4AvAD45SlatxsA7ow7VkAb2S47uaZgB0AWWkA1FiPl5duOAAMADS29gHaenAhSPa4ADy44X6EJORUdIzUrJzcvIKi4hIAtArKaurRsQD6EbgSGDjqLiw0TgBiIgD2naoSza3EnRSBEqWGmmD+6sgAvgDcQA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Всё просто: `int.MinValue` равен `-2147483648`, а `MaxValue` — `2147483647`, т.е. `-int.MaxValue` приводит к переполнению, но т.к. вы выполняете программу в unchecked mode, то все переполнения игнорируются и на выходе вы получаете то же `-2147483648`, а log'а из отрицательного числа нету, поэтому `NaN`.

Просто создайте исключение для `int.MinValue`.

Answer (score 6):

Можно просто в лоб посчитать число разрядов:

```
public int Digits(int num)
{
    if (num == 0)
        return 1;

    var result = 0;
    
    while(num > 0)
    {
        num = num / 10;
        result++;
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Ваш подход тоже рабочий:

```
public int Digits(int number)
{
    if (number == 0)
        return 1;
    
    var num = Math.Abs(number);
    
    var result = Math.Log10(num) + 1; 
    
    return (int) result;
}
```

Набор юнит-тестов:

```
[Test]
[TestCase(0, 1)]
[TestCase(1, 1)]
[TestCase(2, 1)]
[TestCase(3, 1)]
[TestCase(9, 1)]
[TestCase(10, 2)]
[TestCase(42, 2)]
[TestCase(99, 2)]
[TestCase(100, 3)]
[TestCase(123, 3)]
[TestCase(1979, 4)]
[TestCase(-2147483648, 10)]
[TestCase(2147483647, 10)]
public void SolutionTests(int num, int expected)
{
    var actual = new Solution().Digits(num);
    Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected));
}
```

PS [А этот подход вообще самый быстрый, основан на технике divide and conquer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1306727)

```
public int Digits(int num)
{
    if(num == int.MinValue)
        return 10;
        
    if(num<0)
        return Digits(-num);
        
    if (num < 100000) {
        // 5 or less
        if (num < 100){
            // 1 or 2
            if (num < 10)
                return 1;
            else
                return 2;
        } else {
            // 3 or 4 or 5
            if (num < 1000)
                return 3;
            else {
                // 4 or 5
                if (num < 10000)
                    return 4;
                else
                    return 5;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // 6 or more
        if (num < 10000000) {
            // 6 or 7
            if (num < 1000000)
                return 6;
            else
                return 7;
        } else {
            // 8 to 10
            if (num < 100000000)
                return 8;
            else {
                // 9 or 10
                if (num < 1000000000)
                    return 9;
                else
                    return 10;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможно, стоит захардкодировать ещё int.MinValue

Comment: @VladD Да, подход автора с формулой логарифма даёт неверный результат. Спасибо за замечание!

Comment: Если существует решение, значит существует Linq про него `int Digits(int num) => Enumerable.Repeat(false, int.MaxValue).Select(_ => num /= 10).TakeWhile(n => n != 0).Count() + 1;`

Comment: @aepot кажется вы промахнулись мимо поля "ответ" :)

Answer (score 3):

А вы посмотрите, чему равно `int.MinValue` и чему равно `int.MaxValue`. В силу особенностей представления чисел, `Abs(MinValue)` обычно на 1 больше, чем `MaxValue` для любых целочисленных данных (не только для `int`), поэтому `-int.MinValue` на 1 больше чем `int.MaxValue` и уже не помещается в тип `int`. Но эту проблему наверное можно решить принудительным преобразованием `-((long)number)`.

Answer (score 0):

мне кажется проще так

```
    sum = sum < 0 ? sum.ToString().Length - 1 : sum.ToString().Length;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static byte GetLengthWithCascadedIfElse(int number)
    { 
        if (number > 9 || number < (-9))
        {
            return (byte)(GetLengthWithCascadedIfElse(number / 10) + 1);
        }
      
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

> Можно решить с помощью рекурсивной функции